# Inequality similar to König's Lemma

Tags: set-theory

If $I$ is an set containing more than 2 elements, $A_i,\,B_i$ are sets for every $i \in I$, and $\#A_i < \#B_i$ for every $i \in I$ then

$$\sum_{i\in I}\#A_i < \prod_{i\in I}\#B_i$$

Will inequality hold if we have $1<\#A_i \le \#B_i$ ?

Comment: Not when $I$ is a single-element set and $A_i = B_i$.

Comment: @sdcvvc oh sorry not to consider $I$ containing 1 or 2 element set I forgot to mention.

Comment: Why is this tagged with the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if the sharp inequality is violated for some $A_i,B_i$, then it is violated for $A_i = B_i$. Therefore, the question can be simplified to: given that $1<\#A_i$, is it true that $\sum_{i \in I} A_i < \prod_{i \in I} A_i$? Supposing $A_i$ is independent of $i$, this reduces to $A \cdot I < A^I$, which is false when $A=2^I$ and $I$ is infinite (both sides are then $2^I$) or when $I$ is finite and $A$ is infinite (both sides are then $A$).